# General Google Sheet weirdness: ranges, functions, and javascript peculiarities eg Math.trunc missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There seem to be a bunch of undocumented javascript issues in google sheets.

ranges in arguments are some represented by idiosyncratic object. For example, let's say I have

```
function myfunction(range){  // A1:A3, contents [1, 2, 3]
  range.length == 1;  // true
  range.toString();   // "1,2,3"
  range.toString().split(","); // ["1","2","3"], .length 3
}
```

the documentation says it's returned as an array, but it's clearly not a standard JavaScript array.

The second annoying issue is that `Math.trunc()` is not implemented, but the code sheet seems to recognize it (doesn't cause a load error). In a function, however, it's an identity: `Math.trunc(91.9080)` returns `91.9080`.

The range one really seems like I must have some basic misunderstanding — surely the documentation wouldn't be that far wrong in that peculiar a way. But I couldn't find any documentation; I had to work it out by experimentation, which turns a one-hour favor for a friend into a weekend-long project.

The other one is less annoying, possibly because after working out the range thing I was pre-suspicious about weird behaviors.

So, at last, the real question: is this documented? Was there (with ranges) some incantation I was missing?

**Update**

Okay, the answer is that what is passed is not an array but an object which contains an array. The documentation does not make that clear, to say the least. But thanks for pointing out the Range object which eliminates the need for my `arg.toString().split(',')` hack.

[image: Google documentation from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Can you explicitly illustrate how you instantiated the argument you're providing to `myfunction(range)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Range objects

[`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) isn't an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's one of many classes implemented to provide a programmatic interface to Google Sheets.

However, the [`Range.getValues()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a two-dimensional array containing the values of the cells represented by a `Range` instance.

To illustrate, given a sheet that looks like this:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
```

And the following function:

```
function testRange() {
  // Get a range object representing cells A1:A3.
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A3");

  // The range object does not have a length property.
  Logger.log("range.length: " + range.length);

  // Obtain a two dimensional array of values from the Range object.
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Demonstrate the layout of the two-dimensional array. The first two 
  // results should be true, representing the outer and one of the inner arrays.
  // The final result should be false, as it contains the value of cell A1.
  Logger.log("Array.isArray(values): " + Array.isArray(values));
  Logger.log("Array.isArray(values[0]): " + Array.isArray(values[0]));
  Logger.log("Array.isArray(values[0][0]): " + Array.isArray(values[0][0]));

  // Traverse the two-dimensional array and log it's contents.
  var numRows = values.length;
  var numColumns = values[0].length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      Logger.log("Row " + (i+1) + ", Column " + (j+1) + ": " + values[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

You get the following logging output from executing the function:

```
[19-12-16 11:44:53:146 PST] range.length: undefined
[19-12-16 11:44:53:254 PST] Array.isArray(values): true
[19-12-16 11:44:53:254 PST] Array.isArray(values[0]): true
[19-12-16 11:44:53:255 PST] Array.isArray(values[0][0]): false
[19-12-16 11:44:53:255 PST] Row 1, Column 1: 1
[19-12-16 11:44:53:256 PST] Row 2, Column 1: 2
[19-12-16 11:44:53:256 PST] Row 3, Column 1: 3
```

---

### Math built-in

Regarding `Math.trunc()`, when I attempt to execute this example function:

```
function testMathTrunc() {
  Logger.log(Math.trunc(91.9080));
}
```

If fails with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function trunc in object [object Math].
```

So in this case, more context about your code is necessary to reproduce what you're seeing.

It is also worth noting that [the Apps Script run time is based on an older version of Javascript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features):

> Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6, plus a few features from 1.7 and 1.8.

This explains the lack of a `Math.trunc()` implementation and is something to generally keep in mind, especially if you're used to using ES6+ features.

---

### Custom functions

In the context of [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), for the sake of convenience, an A1 notation argument is automatically converted to either a value (if a single a cell is specified) or a 2-dimensional array of values (if a cell range is specified).

In order to clearly see this, it's better to utilize `JSON.stringify()` instead of `Array.toString()`. Given the following custom function implementation:

```
function TEST_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(values) {
    return JSON.stringify(values);
}
```

Using that custom function in the above sheet like so:

```
=TEST_CUSTOM_FUNCTION(A1:A3)
```

Results in the cell being populated with:

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

The key here is that using JSON accurately depicts the data structure, while `Array.toString()` does not.

These are normal Javascript `Array` objects and the way the range of values is structured matches my example above (i.e. when using `Range.getValues()`).

It makes sense to always return a two-dimensional array for a range of cells, as the layout of values within the data structure allows you to reason about the layout of the spreadsheet cells.

This is pertinent when [a custom function returns a two-dimensional array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values) (which then overflows the returned values into adjacent cells). If the input isn't provided as a two-dimensional array for single dimensional ranges, you'd be unable to differentiate between whether you're working with a column or a row of cells. See [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization) for a concrete case where this is relevant (i.e. beyond the ambiguity a 1-dimensional array would introduce, the function would have to be more complicated if 1-dimensional arrays had to be specially accounted for).

At the end of the day, it's simpler to represent a range of cells in a consistent way, particularly in the context of a general purpose API.

Comment: I figured it couldn't possibly be an error in the google sheets code. But I didn't see the Range object mentioned in the examples I found in the documentation. Sadly, if you run the function in the code editor, I'm sure it does that. Running it into a cell in the spreadsheet does not.

Comment: See my update: the documentation says it's an array. Ergo my confusion.

Comment: Technically, it says, "the argument will be a two-dimensional array." I've updated my answer to include a discussion of custom functions.

Comment: I also noticed your comment on the other answer expressing your expectation of a 1-dimensional array given a 1-dimensional selection. I've addressed that concern as well.

Comment: Yeah, for an example that is a 2D array. It's at least misleading.

Comment: Similarly on the JavaScript version. It's kind of like the problem with old man pages: they assume that you're already familiar with the rest of the documentation. If the introduction text said "this is a limited version of JavaScript" and "*always* returns a 2D array" it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Sheet values passed to custom functions called using the in-sheet =functionname() syntax are either a single value (for a single cell), or a two-dimension array (for a range of cells). This behaves as documented. Your "myfunction()" code behaves as expected when receiving range values of 1 row with three columns.

The confusion around the length when converting to string and back is about the behaviour of array.tostring(), not an issue with Apps Script.

Math.trunc() is not implemented, and raises an error when called.

```
function testmyfunction(){
  var values = [[1,2,3]];
  myfunction(values);
}

function myfunction(range){  
  Logger.log(range);  //[[1,2,3]]

  Logger.log((range.length == 1));  // true
  Logger.log(range.toString());   // "1,2,3"
  Logger.log(range.toString().split(",").length); // ["1","2","3"], .length 3
  Logger.log(Math.trunc(range[0][0]));  //raises exception
}
```

Comment: Yep, and wouldn't it be marvelous if that Range object were documented somewhere in, say, an example. Oh, I'm sure it's there, somewhere, but extensive googling about weird behavior of ranges didn't reveal it.

Comment: you can find the Range docs here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.  It's a bit challenging to parse your expectations because you seem to be using the idea of the Range and the values of the Range interchangeably. The Range object represents a Range in the sheet, akin to a selection of cells, you could use the Range object to apply formatting or do other cell-level operations. The values within the cells are independent of that and are returned as a simple array (via getValues).  General guide here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: See my update. The documentation refers to returning an array, and says "if you select a two-dimensional range you get a two-dimensional array". But if you select a one-dimensional range, it still returns a (degenerate) two-dimensional array. My expectation was that if you select a one-dimensional range you get a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Oh, and the function behaves as expected iff you expect to get an array of arrays for a one-dimensional range.

Comment: it's clear now you are calling the code as a custom function from the sheet, so in that case the Range object doesn't actually factor in. You receive either a single value from a single cell, or you get a two-dimensional array for a range of cells.

Comment: Exactly — it's a degenerate 2D array.